# Finding duplicate rows on some columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, grouping

I have the following data frame:

```
# A tibble: 13 x 2
     val Tracking
    <dbl>    <int>
 1    36        1
 2    36        2
 3    36        3
 4    36        4
 5    18        5
 6    18        6
 7     1        1
 8     7        2
 9     7        3
10     7        4
11     7        5
12     7        6
13    20        1
```

The column "Tracking" indicates in which row in a second data frame the value appears. So for example the value 36 appears in rows 1, 2, 3, 4 of the second data frame.

Now, I would like to construct a function which returns the value that appear in the same rows, and how many times. For example, the values 36 and 7 both appear in rows 2,3,4, so my output should be something like (36,7, c(2,3,4)).

I have gotten as far as constructing the table

```
T_d <-  table(df_d$val, df_d$Tracking)

     1 2 3 4 5 6
  1  1 0 0 0 0 0
  7  0 1 1 1 1 1
  18 0 0 0 0 1 1
  20 1 0 0 0 0 0
  36 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

But it is still not exactly what I need.

I need a high performance solution, that is suitable for very large data frames, and if possible dplyr rather than data.table (I don't speak data.table.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Tracking) %>%
  summarise(val_combined = paste(val, collapse=",")) %>%
  group_by(val_combined) %>%
  summarise(Tracking_combined = paste(Tracking, collapse=","))
```

**Output is:**

```
  val_combined Tracking_combined        
1 18,7         5,6              
2 36,1,20      1                
3 36,7         2,3,4
```

**Sample data:**

```
df <- structure(list(val = c(36L, 36L, 36L, 36L, 18L, 18L, 1L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 20L), Tracking = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 1L)), .Names = c("val", "Tracking"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13"
))
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be solved using two successive `aggregate` functions:

```
agg <- aggregate(val ~ Tracking, data = df, c)
agg$val <- paste(agg$val) # Change list output to character
aggregate(Tracking ~ val, data = agg, c)
```

**Intermediate output:**

```
agg

  Tracking       val
1        1 36, 1, 20
2        2     36, 7
3        3     36, 7
4        4     36, 7
5        5     18, 7
6        6     18, 7
```

**Final output:**

```
                 val Tracking
1       c("18", "7")     5, 6
2 c("36", "1", "20")        1
3       c("36", "7")  2, 3, 4
```

**Sample Data:**

```
df <- data.frame(val= c(36,36,36,36,18,18,1,7,7,7,7,7,20), 
                 Tracking=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose You have table named Table1 and Table2.And they have Foreign key relation like Table1's primary key is the Foreign key for Table2's primary key(PKID).
Here's the query

```
SELECT PKID FROM TABLE2 HAVING COUNT(PKID)>1 GROUP BY PKID;
```